# How to group by same column on different levels in SQL?

Tags: sql

Sorry, but I'm not sure how to describe this clearly in words.

Basically I have data like

```
name    tier    value1  value2  value3  month
Andy    1       1       2       3       1
Bob     3       2       3       1       1
Candy   2       3       1       1       1
Daniel  1       1       1       3       1
Edward  3       1       3       1       1
Frank   3       2       2       2       1
Andy    2       1       2       2       2
Bob     2       2       1       1       2
Candy   1       2       3       2       2
Daniel  1       3       1       3       2
Edward  3       1       1       1       2
Frank   3       2       3       2       2
```

What I want is like

```
month   tier    sum(value1) sum(value2) sum(value3)
1       1       2           3           6
1       2       3           1           1
1       3       5           8           4
1       1or2    5           4           7
1       1or2or3 10          12          11
2       1       5           4           5
2       2       3           3           3
2       3       3           4           3
2       1or2    8           7           8
2       1or2or3 11          11          11
```

I think I can run the same aggregation logic with 3 different `group by` and union the results, but is there a better way?

Comment: Check out GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP.

Comment: @O.Jones Thank you so much! This is exactly what I need. Sorry I dun have the right to upvote your comment though.

Comment: You're welcome.  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/w8FQzXYkZz1DxVWKYx4JK6/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better if you create a dimension table which keep all possible tier cases with tier values:

[image]

Then that query could help:

```
select t.month, 
       tr.tier_case as tier, 
       sum(t.sum_value1) as sum_value1,
       sum(t.sum_value2) as sum_value2,
       sum(t.sum_value3) as sum_value3
  from tiers tr
  join (
        select month,  
               tier, 
               sum(value1) as sum_value1,
               sum(value2) as sum_value2,
               sum(value3) as sum_value3
          from table t
         group by 1,2
       )t
    on tr.tier = t.tier
 group by 1,2
```